# html5 - using formatted placeholder for scientific inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was Creating an WebApp which requires to take Percentages of various Chemicals like (HCl[`Hydrochloric acid`], NaOH`[Sodium Hydroxide`] etc) as Input from User.

So Here is what I'm Doing to do that in `HTML`:

```
<input type='text' value='' name='hcl' placeholder='Enter HCl%' />
```

and this works fine in most of  the cases, But Now My Client have an requirement of Entering Percentage of Chemicals like H<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>, SiO<sub>2</sub> etc.

So Here is what I've Used for that:

```
<input type='text' placeholder='H<sub>2</sub>O' />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1zvrtzo/)

But with No Success.

---

So Now I have a question:

**How can we Format `placeholders` of `html input` to show Formatted Text like the one mentioned here?**

---

I know the **possible solution** to this scenario is:

Use `label` outside of `<input>` which will have that formatted text inside it like:

```
<label for='h2o'>Enter H<sub>2</sub>O% :</label><input id='h2o' type='text' />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1zvrtzo/1/) and also I'm using this approach right now;

---

But Still I'm curious in knowing can it be done with placeholders too?

Using CSS or CSS3?

If not Then using JS?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Hope Experts will help me with this. Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: This can't be done with placeholders, or with input text, since an input can only contain a string of text as its value, none of which can be independently styled.

Comment: It seems that you intend to use placeholders instead of appropriate labels for controls. This bad for usability and especially for accessibility, as noted in the HTML5 description of the `placeholder` attribute. So you should stick to the approach you are using now.

Comment: How are the users entering the subscripts, anyway? Are they using Unicode too?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Users don't need to do that, they only enter Percentage.

Comment: @VedantTerkar, then I think the placeholder is misleading. Placeholders are meant to show example input, as far as I know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try to use Unicode characters for [subscript numbers](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html) ("Subscript Codes" section):

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="H&#8322;O" />
```

See available sub/superscripts table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts.

Another option (if say some browser doesn't support necessary character) you can always use background image with the text, and hide background on `input:focus`.

Comment: As I said I would simply create an image of the necessary placeholder and use it as a background for IE specifically, and hide it on `input:focus {background: none;}`.

Comment: Combine with downloadable font-face in the CSS, and you can guarantee the characters are provided on any browser recent enough to support `placeholder`. I would note that generally it's preferred that one use markup like `<sub>` over subscript numbers from Unicode when that will work, as per http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr20/

Comment: How about using `H₂O` instead of `H&#8322;O`?

Answer (score 1):

You can style the entire placeholder using css like this

```
/*For Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) */

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */  
}

/* For Mozilla Firefox */

input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Your style here e.g. font size, color etc */
}
```

You can also style some part using :after and :before selectors

```
//for wbkit browsers
::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
     content: '*';
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
     content: '*';
}

//similarly for moz browsers
```

Another way is to use UTF characters as suggested by @dfsq